# How to display an image from an external API as part of a response in Django

Tags: python, django, rest

I have an external API that returns images and it requires a private key in order to access it. The content type it returns is 'image/jpeg'.

I am creating an API with the Django Rest Framework that uses this API. I also have a model with some basic char entries, and I want to return both those model entries as well as the image in a response, with the goal of making AJAX calls to it in JS and displaying both the data and the image in HTML.

I'm not exactly sure if I need to use Django forms? or if I can just make a call to the API in a plain js file hosted in my project? the latter would be ideal if I am able to send the image as part of the response... but ofcourse I don't want to expose the API key, which is part of the URL I am making a request to to get the image. I just want to essentially download the image and send it as a response.

This is the current code I have been testing out:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def random_image(request):

    response = requests.get('api url with secret key')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type="image/jpeg")
```

I'm able to get an image response and see it when I make a GET request to the url in postman, however in Chrome I get a 500 server error.

Comment: You are passing to `HttpResponse` the raw `requests` response object. You must pass a `str` or `bytes` object. In other words, `HttpResponse(response.content, content_type="image/jpeg")`

Comment: @Ivan Lendl first convert response to a proper data type like `json` then in template get data and call for example `context.image` inside an `<img src=context.image>`. `context.image` is definitely is an address

Comment: You can also try the Django `FileResponse` object that is more suitable for this task: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
HttpResponse(response, ...)
```

To

```
HttpResponse(response.content, ...)
```

Should solve your issue my friend